# Sizing UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

So this is my first time working with CollectionView and I have collection of images and I want my collection hight to adjust to show all the images so I do not have to scroll to see the rest of them

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MycellCollectionViewCell
        cell.myimage.image = UIImage(named: list[indexPath.row]+".jpg")
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Pls share the code of what you have done so far?

Comment: I did not add any code I was trying to fix it with constraint

Comment: how much count you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the height of `UICollectionView` by using the `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)` method after calling `reloadData()`

```swift
var height = CGFloat(0)
self.collectionView.reloadData()
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil) { (result) in
    if result {
        height = self.collectionView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

After that you can either set the frame height of the collection view:

`collectionView.frame.size.height = height`

or add a constraint:

```swift
let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: collectionView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: height)
collectionView.addConstraint(height)
```

or if you have set the the collectionview's height from the storyboard or XIB, then you can connect the constraint to your code and simply change the constant:

`collectionHeight.constant = height`